# Как выравнивать уравнения в системе? LaTeX

Tags: latex, выравнивание

Доброго времени суток.

Как выравнивать уравнения в системе по столбцам неизвестных величин в LaTeX?

Например:

```
  x1-2*x2     =4
     6*x2  -x3=7
3*x1     +8*x3=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, если вас устраивают пробелы между частями:

```latex
\begin{array}{rrrl}
x_1  & {} - 2x_2 &           & {} = 4 \\
     &      6x_2 & {} - x_3  & {} = 7 \\
3x_1 &           & {} + 8x_3 & {} = 2
\end{array}
```

[Пример](https://www.HostMath.com/Show.aspx?Code=%5Cbegin%7Barray%7D%7Brrrl%7D%0Ax_1%20%26%20%7B%7D%20-%202x_2%20%26%20%26%20%7B%7D%20%3D%204%20%5C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%26%206x_2%20%26%20%7B%7D%20-%20x_3%20%26%20%7B%7D%20%3D%207%20%5C%5C%0A3x_1%20%26%20%26%20%7B%7D%20%2B%208x_3%20%26%20%7B%7D%20%3D%202%0A%5Cend%7Barray%7D)

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Что за пробелы вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Расстояние между столбцами

Comment: Так и нужно, спасибо.